# ASP Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) error in server

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my asp code

```
<link id="Link1" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="~/Styles/css/tableStyle.css" />
    <link id="Link2" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="~/Styles/css/LoadingStyle.css" />
    <link id="Link3" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="~/Styles/css/selectStyle.css" />
```

The page opens but with no style, I mean the tables and selects doesn't have the style that I make for them.

#### I tried

click f12 on google chrome so I got these errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:31200/~/Styles/css/selectStyle.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:31200/~/Styles/css/LoadingStyle.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:31200/~/Styles/css/tableStyle.css
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because if you browse to `http://localhost:31200/~/Styles/css/selectStyle.css` there is no such resource.

You probably want `http://localhost:31200/Styles/css/selectStyle.css`. So, remove the `~` symbol in your `href`:

```
<link id="Link1" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="/Styles/css/tableStyle.css" />
<link id="Link2" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="/Styles/css/LoadingStyle.css" />
<link id="Link3" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="/Styles/css/selectStyle.css" />
```

Comment: What JavaScript? There is none in your question?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by [Belogix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1449206/belogix). This error can also be caused if the developer has not enabled

`app.UseStaticFiles()`

in the startup code.
Make sure that line is present in your Startup code and the error should be resolved.